# how to write <img> tag when MVC3 thinks .jpg is a property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, text, razor

I need to write

```
<img src="/view/pano/@img.ImageName/@img.ImageName.jpg"
```

But the problem is that MVC3 thinks .jpg is a property of ImageName.
How can I tell it that this is just clear text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@{
    var src = string.Format( "/view/pano/{0}/{0}.jpg", img.ImageName );
}

<img src="@src" alt="..." />
```

or you could move the construction of the string inline, but I find that less readable.

```
<img src="@string.Format( "/view/pano/{0}/{0}.jpg", img.ImageName )" alt="..." />
```